# Program for decrypt linux shadow file

Tags: linux, password, pam, cryptography

Is there any program or script available for decrypt Linux shadow file ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Passwords on a linux system are not encrypted, they are hashed which is a huge difference.

It is not possible to reverse a hash function by definition.
For further information see the [Hash Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Which hash function is used, depends on your system configuration. [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and [blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)) are common examples for used hash functions.

So the "real" password of a user is never stored on the system.

If you login, the string you enter as the password will be hashed and checked against your /etc/shadow file. If it matches, you obviously entered the correct password.

Anyway there are still some attack vectors against the password hashes. You could keep a dictionary of popular passwords and try them automatically. There are a lot of dictionaries available on the internet. Another approach would be to just try out all possible combinations of characters which will consume a huge amount of time. This is known as bruteforce attack.

[Rainbowtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) are another nice attack vector against hashes. The idea behind this concept, is to simply pre calculate all possible hashes and then just lookup a hash in the tables to find the corresponding password. There are several [distributed computing projects to create such tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table), the size differs on the characters used and is mostly several TB.

To minimize the risk of such lookup tables its a common practice and the default behaviour in Unix/Linux to add a so called "[salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))" to the password hash. You hash your password, add a random salt value to the hash and hash this new string again. You need to save the new hash and the salt to be able to check if a entered value is the correct password. The huge advantage of this method is, that you would have to create new lookup tables for each unique salt.

A popular tool to execute dictionary or brute force attacks against user passwords of different operating systems is [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) (or JTR).
See the [project homepage](http://www.openwall.com/john/) for more details:

> John the Ripper is a fast password
>   cracker, currently available for many
>   flavors of Unix, Windows, DOS, BeOS,
>   and OpenVMS. Its primary purpose is to
>   detect weak Unix passwords.

Comment: Is there any animation tutorials available for explain  about those things ?

Comment: Which things? I don't know any, but IMHO the linked resources explain the topics clear enough and I'm sure you will find much more information if you put a little effort in searching/reading.

Comment: I think they're asking for a youtube tutorial because reading comprehension is an overrated skill these days.

Answer (score 2):

You can only decrypt the shadow file by brute force: It includes hashes of the passwords, so your only chance is to guess passwords, calculate the hash and look if the hashes are identical. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28Unix%29#Library_Function) for details about the hash generation.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can't really decrypt the shadow file.

The only thing you can try is to brute-force guess the password using a tool like [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/).
This may or may not succeed, and will almost certainly take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

It is practically impossible to decrypt those paswords since they are one-way encrypted.

Comment: Can you pls tell about one-way encrypted ?

Comment: One-Way encrypted means that you don't store the password but just its hash value. And the special property of the hash is that you cannot recreate the password from it. Think of it like only storing a number like the amount of letters. If i store a "5", I can then quickly check whether the word "Kumar" can be the password. But from "5" I cannot calculate back to "Kumar" (simplified example, the hash is more complex and collisions are way less common (if not rare) with modern hashing algorithms)

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are encrypted using an algorithm that will take a password and create a hash that is unique to that password. This hash is stored in the /etc/shadow file. It is not possible to recover the password from the hash. The only methods of recovering a password is to either [**brute force**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_force_attack) the entire keyspace or to use some sort of [**dictionary**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attack) attack. Early hash functions used the DES standard. The increase in computing power has made it possible to brute force the DES keyspace in a reasonable time. Modern hash functions used to encrypt passwords include MD5, SHA etc. More information on the crypt(3) library can be found [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28Unix%29).